# Custom layout manager for an image gallery?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, linearlayoutmanager

I'm need your help with `LayoutManager`. Here is a picture of what i need:

[image]

I tried `StagerredGridLayoutManager` but rows have constant width. I don't know if i need to write a custom layout manager in this case? If so, I have no idea how to resize spans based on image width.

Comment: use this:  mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

Comment: @SagarChavada how will it change span count?

Comment: its depend on your images width and height. so do not set everything fix size. set images and layout as wrap_content, so it will never be a fixed size.

Comment: @SagarChavada its not working and its shouldn't. if you have 3 spans sizes will change only inside spans. But what it looks like, its adjusting span size or occupies multiply spans